# Howto make a service listen on a specific docker network only?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have docker services that are attached to several networks.
For example - a service would be attached to a traefik ingress network - and several other networks, such as etcd or minio. A compose file might look like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  myservice:
    image: ...
    command: server --listen=0.0.0.0:8080
    networks:
      - public
      - internal-api
      - etcd
```

Now, currently, we can see in my example the listen address of 0.0.0.0:8080
But this is not what I want - I want this service to only listed on the `public` interface and not be discoverable on the `etcd` or `internal-api` networks.

How can I - generally, specify which docker network I want a service to listen on?

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Keep your container connected only to necessary networks (which is best practice)
2. `command: server --listen=< CONTAINER IP IN SPECIFIC NETWORK >:8080`
3. Setup firewall in container

Comment for second option:

One way is to setup static IP using docker-compose file or you can get IP of currently running container with command:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <CONTAINER_NAME>
```

Comment: 1. yes. but the set of networks that is necessary is always larger than the set of networks you might want to listen on.
2. This touches the core issue :- how to obtain the container-ip-in-specific-network?
3. seems like overkill if problem 2 can be solved.